# What are the most significant confirmed instances of match-rigging in football?

Tags: football, match-fixing

What are the most significant *confirmed* (i.e. investigated by the governing body and punished) instances of match-rigging in football? When considering significance, please include:

- Level of the match: a World Cup match would be more significant than some Sunday morning pub football.
- Degree of match-rigging: arranging for a team to win is more significant than [the time of the first throw-in](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/teams/southampton/6130280/Matthew-Le-Tissier-admits-being-part-of-attempted-betting-scam-at-Southampton.html).
- Effect of the match-rigging: something which enabled the team to win a league is more important than the difference between 12th and 13th place.
- Amount of match-rigging: more rigged matches is more significant.

Comment: The original question here ("Was Barcelona vs Roma rigged") is definitely off-topic here because we are a fact based site, and nobody has any actual facts on the subject. I've tried to rewrite this into a question which might stay open here. It's still a bit list-based and a bit opinion-based, but it's got a better chance. You are welcome to revert the change if you wish, but I'm pretty sure it will then be closed in short order.

Answer (score 8):

There are definitely not as many match-fixing scandals in football as conspiracy theorists might have expected. Especially on such a high level, which your original question suggested.

One of the most popular match-fixing scandals that happened recently was Italian [Calciopoli scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Italian_football_scandal), where many Serie A clubs were accused of rigging games by selecting favorable referees, during 2004/05 and 2005/06 seasons. As a result:

- **Juventus** was stripped of both 2004–05 and 2005–06 Serie A titles, was downgraded to 2006-07 Serie B while also receiving a handicap of starting with -9 points.
- **Fiorentina** was deducted 30 points from their 2005–06 Serie A run, making them finish 9th instead of 4th. Also received a handicap of starting with -15 points in the next season.
- **Milan** was deducted 30 points from 2005–06 Serie A, making them finish 3rd instead of 2nd. Received a handicap of -8 points in the next season.
- **Lazio** was deducted 30 points from 2005–06 Serie A, making them finish 16th instead of 6th. Received a handicap of -3 points in the next season.
- **Reggina** Received a handicap of -11 points in the next season.
- **Siena** Received a handicap of -1 point in the next season.

Here you can find a list of some minor [match-fixing incidents in football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_match_fixing_incidents#Association_football) most of which don't really meet the requirements of the edited question.

Answer (score 4):

I think the [Hoyzer Scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesliga_scandal_(2005)) is of enough significance.

The former referee Robert Hoyzer manipulated several matches in the German Cup (DFB-Pokal), 2. Bundesliga and Regionalliga. He was sentenced to serve 2 years and 5 months for match fixing in 6 cases.

List of matches he refereed:

DFB-Pokal:

- 21. August 2004: SC Paderborn 07 – Hamburger SV 4-2 (manipulated)
- 21. September 2004: 1. FC Nürnberg – LR Ahlen 2-3 (no proof of manipulation)

2. Bundesliga:

- 27. August 2004: Rot-Weiss Essen – Rot-Weiß Erfurt 0-0 (no proof)
- 26. September 2004: MSV Duisburg – SpVgg Greuther Fürth 1-0 (protest by Fürth and probably manipulated, but not enough proof)
- 22. October 2004: LR Ahlen – Wacker Burghausen 1-0 (manipulated and replayed)
- 28. November 2004: SpVgg Unterhaching – 1. FC Saarbrücken 1:3 (manipulation failed)

- And some Regionalliga matches

Answer (score -1):

The most notable one is the 2006 scandal in the Serie A. Teams involved were Juve, Fiorentina, Milan and Lazio. Out of them, Juve were relegated to Serie B and stripped of their 2005 and 2006 Serie A titles. Many notable footballers like Zlatan Ibrahimovic, Gianluca Zambrotta, Patrick Vieira, Fabio Cannavaro left the club not wanting to play in a lower division. However, Players like Gigi Buffon, Alessandro Del Piero, Chiellini stayed loyal to the Old Lady. Even then Coach Fabio Capello left the Club.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to gdrt's answer.